How to find item from one list in another
I have some product items in a cart. A customer has already placed an order for ONE of the items in his cart, in the past.
I am trying to get a list of orders he has placed in the past (accomplished by GetOrders).
Pass in the items in his cart to my method (pass in *items *in my method)
Check if any of the cart items match the orderItems
public bool ProductFound(IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItems> items)
{
var orders = GetOrders();

foreach (var order in orders)
{
    if (items.Intersect(order.OrderItems).Any())
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}

I produce the above code but even though i know there is the same product in orderItems and items it never returns true. I then tried order.OrderItems.ProductId to match the Id but then i had a cast error.
How could i check if one list contains any items in a second list passed in?
I visited this link for reference https://code-maze.com/csharp-check-if-items-of-a-list-exist-in-another-list/#:~:text=We%20can%20use%20the%20IEnumerable,()%20vs%20Count()%20in%20.
Edit 1
public bool ProductFound(IReadOnlyCollection<OrderItems> items)
{
var orders = GetOrders();

foreach (var order in orders)
{
  foreach (var i in orders.OrderItems)
    {
     if (items.Contains(i))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }
}

return false;
}


What equality comparer is implemented for type of order? I suspect there is none implemented, therefore Intersect will use reference equality. And seems like you want to have meaningful equality check based on data, not just compare references.

Do you mean change my code to what i have changed it to under Edit 1?

Not really. Just implement an IEqualityComparer and pass an instance of that to Intersect. Your implementation in Edit 1 still just compares references. Based on what criterea would you consider two OrderItems "the same"? Those are what you need to match.

If a custom class has not overriden Equals and GetHashCode or you don't pass a custom IEqualityComparer<T> to Intersect, just references are compared because only you know that you want to compare by ProductId. So either use a different approach:
bool orderedBefore = orders
    .Any(o => items.Select(i => i.ProductId).Intersect(o.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.ProductId)).Any()); 

Or override Equals and GetHashCode to use the ProductId. If you do, you should also implement IEquatable<T>. Then you don't need to project the ProductId.

@KeithViking: Attention when using the "override Equals & HashCode" - approach: This will also affect other places in your code, where you compare that class. So doing it later on in your developoment always yields the danger of breaking something. (Just a thing to be aware of, not saying "don't do it")

@Tim Schmelter When i add the last bit of the code (.Intersect(o.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.ProductId).Any()));) i get the error 'cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable''. Tried changing it around but not sure what i could be missing?

@Fildor it needs to be there, just the parenthesese are off. Should be bool orderedBefore = orders.Any(o => items.Select(i => i.ProductId).Intersect(o.OrderItems.Select(oi => oi.ProductId)).Any());
